# How can i add an LED for identify working status?

Tags: gps

I have a  GPS module, it's working well.
I integrated it with a STM32, getting latitude and longitude values through UART.

How can I connect an LED for indicating the connection status for this module?
Is any pin in this module capable for this purpose?

Thanks..

[DATASHEET](https://www.codico.com/shop/media/datasheets/Quectel_L86_Hardware_Design_V1.1.pdf)

[image]

Comment: This is probably going to have to happen on the STM32 side, it doesn't seem to have any kind of GPIO on the GPS module.

Comment: Thanks  for your information

Comment: look at figure 1 on page 10/45 ... there are only three output pins .... read the descriptions for those pins ... one of them may provide the output that you seek

Answer (score 1):

I recommend lighting the LED using the STM32 since you can determine if a valid lock has been made once you deconstruct the GPS module's messages.

One other possibility:
Some GPS modules allow you to configure them to only output the 1 Hz PPS if a valid connection has been made. If you can configure the module to do this, then you can connect an LED to the 1 Hz PPS signal and it will flash at 1 Hz if a GPS fix has been made.

Note: The default configuration of most modules will simply output the 1 Hz PPS regardless of GPS fix status.